# Can't access proofing options in Outlook 2016

Tags: microsoft-office-2016, microsoft-outlook-2016

I want to disable spell check in my Outlook 2016 mail editor. So I select Options | Editor Options, but the dialog shown shows Advanced options, with Proofing disabled:

[image]

[image]

I know this happens when the Outlook version doesn't match the Word version, like when they're installed separately. But Office 2016 installs everything at once, with zero user options. 
I uninstalled the previous Office version before installing.

How can I access Proofing options?

Comment: Have you tried: "Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Programs and Features" -- Uninstall or change programs -> [Change] -> Microsoft Office; and then select sub-features in outlook (open advanced options when there)? Maybe that will work?

Comment: @ejbytes When I try this, then after choosing Change Microsoft Office I only can choose "Repair", no details. Tried this, and after a couple of minutes it terminated with an error, but the problem is solved! If you make your comment an answer I'll accept it. Thanks.

Comment: Cool! Glad it worked :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried: "Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Programs and Features" -- Uninstall or change programs -> [Change] -> Microsoft Office; and then select sub-features in outlook (open advanced options when there)? Maybe that will work?

- or repair as OP commented works.

  "Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Programs and Features" -- Uninstall or change programs -> [Repair] -> Microsoft Office;